# How create Resource path in mockservice SOAPUI with properties

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui, endpoint

I would like to know if there is any way to do this:

Where ${idProduct} would be a property defined in the `MockService`.

I searched several places, but I did not find anything, could anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Jose, please try the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: Have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you may want to be able to handle the mock service for dynamic product id. Right? Then here is the steps explained with the help of images.

You need to create the mock service with just `/products` and do not have to add the place holder. Then create a response with a place holder property for `productId`.

However, the place holder for `productId` is need while creating the service definition of `Template` type.

For eg: Imagine, you need to handle a request or get product information using endpoint `http://localhost/products/test`, here `test` is the productId for which **Mock Service** have to send the response of product details of input value of the request i.e., `test`.

Say, define the response as below with place holder:

```
{ 
  "product" : "${productId}" 
}
```

Now using Mock Service Dispatch type as `Script` and below is the script which reads the productId from the request and sends it back respective product details

**Script**

```
//Read request, get the productId from request url and assigns productId placeholder
context.productId = mockRequest.path.split('/').last()
```

[image]

**Output** showing how mock service is dealing productId dynamically and sending back the requested info in the response.

[image]

You can find the above soapui project built in version 5.3.0 from [github](https://github.com/nmrao/sample-soapui-projects/blob/master/rest_sample/RestMockSample-soapui-project.xml)